# LDAP authenitcation + DB entity user

Tags: symfony4

I have a requirement where I need to authenticate a user via LDAP but load/sync the user from a `User` entity:

I have read (and re-read) the security docs but this in particular:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html

> The http_basic_ldap authentication provider, for authenticating
>   against an LDAP server using HTTP Basic. Like all other authentication
>   providers, it can be used with any user provider.

Sounds like it should be possible - perhaps by using the LDAP authentication provider with a Doctrine `User` class?

I haven't been able to figure out how to wire this in `security.yaml` and `services.yaml`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [ADLDAP2 library](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2).

This library fits your needs. With ADLDAP2 you can authenticate via LDAP Server and also can load/sync user data.

You can [synchronize any attribute](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/blob/master/docs/auth.md#basic-setup):

```
 'sync_attributes' => [

     'username' => 'samaccountname',
     'name' => 'cn',

 ],
```

Or even [synchronize password](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/blob/master/docs/auth.md#password-synchronization):

> **Password Synchronization**
>
> The password sync option allows you to
>   automatically synchronize users LDAP passwords to your local database.
>   These passwords are hashed natively by laravel.
>
> Enabling this option would also allow users to login to their accounts
>   using the password last used when an LDAP connection was present.
>
> If this option is disabled, the local user account is applied a random
>   16 character hashed password, and will lose access to this account
>   upon loss of LDAP connectivity.
>
> This feature is disabled by default.
>
> `'password_sync' => env('ADLDAP_PASSWORD_SYNC', false),`

There is a [bundle for Symfony](https://github.com/sgomez/adldap2-bundle).

Comment: I should have mentioned...I tried using LdapTools bundle but it gave me a bunch of errors due to the fact I am using S4...plus I really want to better understand the security layers of Symfony :)